# Developing a zooming following window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am devoloping an Android app where I want to display an image, full screen. Then I want to display a small "window" over this image that:

- The window is placed where the user touches the screen.
- The content of this window is a portion of the original image zoomed in. The portion of the image that is zoomed is also defined by the position where the user touches the screen.

This way, as the user moves the finger along the screen, the "window" follows the finger and shows a zoomed version of the original image.

Untill now I was able to do everything I want except to make the content of the "window" update with the zoomed image.

I wrote the following code:

```
public class DetectEyesActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
//DetectEyesView detectEyesView;
//LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
TextView text;
ImageView imgView;
Bitmap imgBitmap;
ImageView touchView2;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.detecteyeslayout);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    byte[] image = intent.getByteArrayExtra("Image");

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detectEyesTextView1);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detectEyesImageView1);

    imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
    //imgView.setOnTouchListener(this);



    text.setTextSize(30);
    text.setText("A");



    touchView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detectEyesImageView2);

    Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap, 200, 200, 200, 200);
    touchView2.setImageBitmap(temp);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //event.getX()
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    float aux = (float)imgBitmap.getHeight() / (float)imgView.getHeight();
    //float imgBitmapHeight = 
    //float imgBitmapWidth = (float)imgBitmap.getWidth()/aux
    float imgDrawableX = (imgView.getWidth() - (float)imgBitmap.getWidth()/aux  ) / 2 + imgView.getX();
    float imgDrawableY = (imgView.getHeight() - (float)imgBitmap.getHeight()/aux  ) / 2 + imgView.getY();
    text.setText("TouchX = " + x + "   TouchY = " + y + " ImageX: "+ imgDrawableX  + " ImageY: "+ imgDrawableY + " aux = " + aux);



    Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap, x, y, 50, 50);
    //touchView2.setImageBitmap(temp);
    touchView2.setVisibility(0);
    touchView2.bringToFront();
    touchView2.layout(x-200, y-200, x-30, y-30);
    touchView2.postInvalidate();
    touchView2.invalidate();
    Log.v("x,y",event.getY()+","+event.getX());



    return true;
}
```

With this code the window follows the finger without updating its content. When I uncomment the line

```
    //touchView2.setImageBitmap(temp);
```

The window simply does not appear. Nevertheless the content of the textView keeps being updated. So I know the onTouchEvent is being executed.

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I might not have the answer to your specific question, allow me to give you my thoughts on your actual code.

If I understand correctly, all you want to do is "move" around a specific image while being able to zoom in.

The first thing that bothers me is this :

- Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap, x, y, 50, 50); *

This means that every time the user touches the screen, you are requesting the CPU of the android device to create a new bitmap.  This seems very risky if, let's say, the user glides his finger on the screen. Tons of ressources must be allocated in a very short amount of time and for no good reason.  You should only create you're bitmap once, and then reuse it in a better way.

This brings up my second point.

Have you considered using OpenGL ES to do this? It would make you're life MUCH easier, assuming you can understand the basis of it.  You would then use the GPU to render the so called Image.  Not to mention that you then can use a very useful "camera" (GluLookAt) to , the name says it all, look at the portion of the image you want, while being able to zoom in and out very easily.

Though I understand that learning OpenGL ES10 might prove far fetched, it would be the most efficient solution.

I hope this can help you somehow!

Comment: @zgui Yes, I am sorry. The lines with Invalidate() and postInvalidade() where some of my desperate atempts to solve the problem.

Comment: zeroxgames: That's is exactly what I want. I want to move around an image while zooming in. I discovered some sort of 'hack' that partially solves my problem. If I only update the bitmap say, each 20 calls to the onTouchEvent(), I get the desired effect. The only problem is that  it flickers a lot.  Is using OpenGL ES10 the only lightweight option? Isn't there any other Android native solution?

Thank you both and to whoever answers me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without postInvalidate() ?
(you do not seem to use multi-threading)
You could also try using a Canvas, as you may need a high refresh rate...
Have a look at this topic on official doc, everything is well explained : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html